# Orbeon to eXist-db loosing query-string

Tags: orbeon

When I call eXist-db directly over port 8877 with a custom header, I have an echo setup that tells me it gets there fine. This route is normally closed on the internet.

When I call eXist-db via Orbeon (3.9) using the page-flow.xml line below, I'm not only loosing that same header, but also the query-parameters in my call.

Page-flow:

```
<page id="fhir" path-info="/fhir/(.*)" matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher" view="http://localhost:8877/fhir/${1}"/>
```

Call (obviously only works on my machine...):

```
curl -v -H "X-Request-Echo: true" http://localhost:8080/art-decor/fhir/ValueSet/?_lastUpdated=%3E2015
```

Is there something that I can do in the configuration of Orbeon? Upgrading Orbeon has proven non-trivial as the css model changed and a lot of pages do not load without a useful error so I'm hoping for a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller only matches on paths, not on query parameters. So the replacement syntax with `${...}` will not have the query string.

In effect, you are trying to proxy the request, is that right? If so, the controller is not the ideal tool for that I fear.

Comment: It does not need to match on query parameters. It only needs to forward exactly the headers and query string I had before forwarding. I'm now loosing info. I solved it for now using httpd/nginx.

Comment: The point is that the controller matches on the *path* only and therefore the regexp group `(.*)`, which is available as `${1}` on the  `view`, only contains what was matched on that path. It forwards neither query parameters nor headers. You are right to use another tool to do this kind of proxying. In short, the controller is not intended to work as a proxy.

Comment: Ouch. That is a rather severe limitation. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe but the controller was never intended to be `mod_rewrite` or `mod_proxy` ;) I would recommend you use instead [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which can work as a proxy.